# Issues in running R from Perl

Tags: r, perl, interfacing

I want to include Statistics::R for my program.
The statement I am including is:

use Statistics::R;

Is there something wrong with it?
I tried to run it with just this statement included, the error i got was

Can't locate Statistics/R.pm in @INC(@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at rperl.pl line 2

By the way I am using perl(v5.14.2) on ubuntu,using remote access to a linux server.

Comment: Did you install [`Statistics::R`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-R/) on the remote server?

Comment: I don't have access to the server but I have been told that it is installed

Comment: Apparently it isn't installed in any of the standard locations so you'll have to talk to who ever is responsible for the server to find out where it is. You might want to get them to check for permissions problems as well.

Comment: Will do that Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install the module as non-root user.
The details are provided in the following link:

http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~you/notes/perl-module-install.html

After doing the things described here, a couple of small steps are to be completed which are mentioned in the following link:

http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations

This worked for me! I hope it would be of help to others too!